# project a linear regression hyper plane to a 2d plot (abline-like)

Tags: r, lm, projection-plane

I have this code

```
factors<-read.csv("India_Factors.csv",header=TRUE)  
marketfactor<-factors[,4]  
sizefactor<-factors[,5]  
valuefactor<-factors[,6]  
dati<-get.hist.quote("SI", quote = "AdjClose", compression = "m")  
returns<-diff(dati)  
regression<-lm(returns ~ marketfactor + sizefactor + valuefactor,na.action=na.omit)
```

that does multilinear regression.
I want to plot on a 2D plane the returns against a factor (and this is trivial of course) with  superimposed the projection of the linear regression hyperplane for the specific factor.  To be more clear the result should be like this: [wolfram demonstrations](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ExpectedReturnsOfTheDowIndustrialsFamaFrenchModel/) (see the snapshots).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time and have a nice week end.
Giorgio.

Comment: I do not wish to sound snarky, but if this is so *trivial* then please show us [**what you have tried**](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). Also, in order to better aid you in your question please make your example [**reproducible**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381). We do not have access to `India_Factors.csv` so can't use your code. Lookup `?dput` to help with sharing data.

Comment: There is a lot if info missing there. The data look centred, are they? By "factors" I don't think you mean it in the R sense; the data look continuous in those Wolfram demos. How do you want to construct the partial plots? By holding the other factors at some pre-specified level (e.g. the mean)?

Answer (score 1):

The points in my comment withstanding, here is the canonical way to generate output from a fitted model in R for combinations of predictors. It really isn't clear what the plots you want are showing, but the ones that make sense to me are partial plots; where one variable is varied over its range whilst holding the others at some common value. Here I use the sample mean when holding a variable constant.

First some dummy data, with only to covariates, but this extends to any number

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100))
dat <- transform(dat,
                 x1 = 0.2 + (0.4 * y) + rnorm(100),
                 x2 = 2.4 + (2.3 * y) + rnorm(100))
```

Fit the regression model

```
mod <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = dat)
```

Next some data values to predict at using the model. You could do all variables in a single prediction and then subset the resulting object to plot only the relevant rows. Alternatively, more clearly (though more verbose), you can deal with each variable separately. Below I create two data frames, one per covariate in the model. In a data frame I generate 100 values over the range of the covariate being varied, and repeat the mean value of the other covariate(s).

```
pdatx1 <- with(dat, data.frame(x1 = seq(min(x1), max(x1), length = 100),
                               x2 = rep(mean(x2), 100)))
pdatx2 <- with(dat, data.frame(x1 = rep(mean(x1), 100),
                               x2 = seq(min(x2), max(x2), length = 100)))
```

In the linear regression with straight lines, you really don't need 100 values --- the two end points of the range of the covariate will do. However for models where the fitted function is *not* linear you need to predict at more locations.

Next, use the model to predict at these data points

```
pdatx1 <- transform(pdatx1, yhat = predict(mod, pdatx1))
pdatx2 <- transform(pdatx2, yhat = predict(mod, pdatx2))
```

Now we are ready to draw the partial plots. First compute a range for the `y` axis - again it is mostly redundant here but if you are adding confidence intervals you will need to include their values below,

```
ylim <- range(pdatx1$y, pdatx2$y, dat$y)
```

To plot (here putting two figures on the same plot device) we can use the following code

```
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))
plot(y ~ x1, data = dat)
lines(yhat ~ x1, data = pdatx1, col = "red", lwd = 2)
plot(y ~ x2, data = dat)
lines(yhat ~ x2, data = pdatx2, col = "red", lwd = 2)
layout(1)
```

Which produces

[image]

Comment: thank you very much G.Simpson, your help was just what I needed. Next time I will post executable code, sorry for my bad posting.